# mock location for testing geofence apps

Tags: android, location, geofencing

I am developing  a very basic app where I am creating a geofence of 5000m radius keeping my location as the center.

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener,
    com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener,
    LocationClient.OnAddGeofencesResultListener {

private LocationClient mLocationClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
// Milliseconds per second
private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
// Update frequency in seconds
public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;
// Update frequency in milliseconds
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
        * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
// The fastest update frequency, in seconds
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 1;
// A fast frequency ceiling in milliseconds
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
        * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

boolean mUpdatesRequested;
private Editor mEditor;
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
private List<Geofence> mGeofenceLists = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);

    mUpdatesRequested = false;
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    mEditor = mPrefs.edit();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    // Location Client Object
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Connect the client.
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    // Save the current setting for updates
    mEditor.putBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", mUpdatesRequested);
    mEditor.commit();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    /*
     * Get any previous setting for location updates Gets "false" if an
     * error occurs
     */
    if (mPrefs.contains("KEY_UPDATES_ON")) {
        mUpdatesRequested = mPrefs.getBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", false);

        // Otherwise, turn off location updates
    } else {
        mEditor.putBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", false);
        mEditor.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("DISCONNECTED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Toast.makeText(this,"lat:  "+location.getLatitude()+"       long: "+location.getLongitude(),
    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    /*
     * try { getAddress(); } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated
     * catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
     */
    // If already requested, start periodic updates

    // Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

    Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder().setRequestId("geo1")
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            .setCircularRegion(89.535354, -88.575510, 5000)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE).build();

    mGeofenceLists.add(geofence);
    mLocationClient.addGeofences(mGeofenceLists,
            getTransitionPendingIntent(), this);

    if (true) { // Need to update when user is asking for updates with
                // mUpdatesRequested
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);

    }

}

private PendingIntent getTransitionPendingIntent() {
    // Create an explicit Intent
    PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, TransitionsIntentService.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return geoFencePendingIntent;

}

/*
 * private void getAddress() throws IOException { // TODO Auto-generated
 * method stub
 * 
 * double latitude = mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude(); double
 * longitude = mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude(); Geocoder
 * geocoder; List<Address> addresses; geocoder = new Geocoder(this,
 * Locale.getDefault()); addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
 * longitude, 1);
 * 
 * String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); String city =
 * addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1); String country =
 * addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
 * 
 * 
 * Toast.makeText(this,"You are at :  "+address+"\n"+city+" ,"+country,
 * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 * 
 * 
 * }
 */

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // System.out.println("LOCATION CHANGE TRIGGERED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    /*
     * String msg = "Updated Location: " +
     * Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
     * Double.toString(location.getLongitude()); Toast.makeText(this, msg,
     * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     */

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public class GeofenceSampleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (TextUtils.equals(action,
                "com.example.android.geofence.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION")) {

            /* handleGeofenceTransition(context, intent); */

            System.out
                    .println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!GEOFENCE in sample receiverTRIGGERED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

        }
    }

}

public class TransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final String TRANSITION_INTENT_SERVICE = "ReceiveTransitionsIntentService";

    public TransitionsIntentService() {
        super(TRANSITION_INTENT_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        System.out
        .println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!GEOFENCE in handle intent TRIGGERED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");


    }
}

@Override
public void onAddGeofencesResult(int statusCode, String[] geofenceRequestIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

I am not getting any triggering in the code.Is it because I am already inside the geofence???
How can I test the entry and exit point with the geofence I have created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to use `MockLocations` myself, to trigger the fence, but I couldn't make it work. 
You can try this:

1. Go to settings, developer options and allow `mockLocations`.
2. Then just download an application to change your gps location, like fakegps or something similar.

It works for me this way.